# call a main class function from another class using delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I have one form and another class file, when i click a button in main form, it passes a value to a function in another class in another file(this function is general purpose which is called by all files) which again calls a function in main form/class and updates textbox.

i have written the code, but it throws exception saying 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

code is here.. plz correct where it is wrong.
main form has button and a textbox.

### main form

```
namespace One
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void WriteToListBoxDelegate(string StringForText);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        int a = 9;

        c1.nnn(a);            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void SetListBox(string StringForText)
    {
        textBox1.Text += DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ": " + StringForText + '\n' + textBox1.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);            
    }

}
}
```

### another class file

```
namespace One
{
public  class Class1
{   
    public One.Form1 theMDIform = new One.Form1();

    public int nnn(int a)
    {

        theMDIform.Invoke(new Form1.WriteToListBoxDelegate(theMDIform.SetListBox), '1');
    return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if i call the function from main function directly from another class and update the textbox, the textbox will lose data when the function control from class function is moved back to main form.

Comment: It would be nice if you pointed out where you get the error...

Comment: the error is thrown at line : theMDIform.Invoke(new Form1.WriteToListBoxDelegate(theMDIform.SetListBox), '1');

Comment: That looks dangerously recursive.

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to execute a function on a window that doesn't exist yet. You know, like your error says? You also have a circular dependency. I suggest you revisit how you are organizing your code. Even if this error is fixed for you now, later on down the road, you are going to run into even more, bigger, problems.

Comment: but its a delegate... it will just execute the call to main form function 'SetListBox' and then update the textbox.

Comment: any suggestion ? because any action in other forms too call this general function 'nnn' of Calss1 and update the textbox in main form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the reference to `Form1` into the `nnn()`:

```
c1.nnn(this, a);
...
public int nnn(Form1 theMDIform, int a)
{
    ...
}
```

and eliminate the `Form1 theMDIform` member from the `Class1` class.

At present you call `nnn()` from a `Form1` object but then you call back another `Form1` object which is incorrect. You need to call back the same `Form1` object.

**Addition**
When you call nnn() from some other form you need to pass a reference to `Form1` as well. So you need the other form to get that reference in some way. A possible solution is to store the reference to `Form1` in a static variable. That will be an implementation of Singleton pattern. I personally don't like that approach here because you may decide to have several `Form1` objects in future:

```
class Form1{
    private static Form1 oInstance;

    // Don't call it from the `Form1` constructor because that
    // will publish the not completely constructed object!
    private void InitInstance(){
        if (oInstance == null)
            oInstance = this;
        else
            throw new SomeException(...);
    }

    public Form1 Instance{
        get{ return oInstance;}
    }
    ...
};
```

then other forms can get the needed reference as `Form1.Instance` and pass it to `nnn()`.

But I would prefer to pass the reference to the `Form1` object to each form e.g. as a constructor argument:

```
class OtherForm{
    private Form1 MainForm;

    public OtherForm(Form1 MainForm){ ...}
}
```

Comment: in case if this nnn is called from another form say Form2. then it will look like this: Form2->nnn->Form1
then the signature of nnn will change. isnt it?

Comment: @johnsonpinto I added the solution to that question to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid tight [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29), I would suggest not to use parctices such as passing your form as an argument (if you must, please use an interface following the [DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) principle), or making `Class1` "requesting" actions from your form.

What I suggest, is to design your program in master-slave manner. your `class1` (posing as slave) should do what it does, and inform whoever wants to know about it's actions using events. your slave class should not be aware of the existence of your higher level master class (AKA your form)

The form will listen to the event, and will take actions that you think fits the events triggered.

At the bottom line, this is not that a big of change from what you currently have. the main difference is that the event `WriteToListBoxDelegate` should be removed, instead of it add `onNnn` event to `class1` and make your form listen to that event.

the code for the event can look something like this:

```
public event EventHandler<StringArgs> onNnn;
public int nnn(int a)
{

    if(this.onNnn != null)
    {
        string s = "any text you want to path";
        StringArgs arg = new StringArgs(s);
        this.onNnn(this,arg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the declaration of `StringArgs`:

```
public class StringArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly string _txt;
    public string Txt
    {
        get { return this._txt; }
    }

    public StringArgs (string txt)
    {
        this._txt = txt;
    }   
}
```

And in your Form add the binding to the event:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    class1Instance.onNnnn += this.HandleClass1Nnn;

}

private voit HandleClass1Nnn(object sender, StringArgs args)
{
     textBox1.Text += args.Txt;
}
```

Comment: this.onNnn(this, theMDIform.SetListBox);
says 'Delegate 'System.EventHandler<One.StringArgs>' has some invalid arguments'
and for class1Instance.onNnnn += this.HandleClass1Nnn;
says 'Class1 doesnot contain definition for onNnn'

Comment: StringArgs arg = new StringArgs(theMDIform.SetListBox);
says 'the best overloaded method match for <One.StringArgs.StringArgs(string)' has some invalid arguments'
what does invalid arguments mean ?

Comment: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'
for the above line of error in Class1 in function 'nnn'

Comment: @johnsonpinto try again.

Comment: no errors but, 'this.onNnn' in Class1 is always null so not updating textbox in Form1.

Comment: It means you did not add the binding in your form. take a look at the constructor code snippet.

Comment: binding is added in Form1 -> 
Class1 class1Instance = new Class1();
and below code is placed in function public Form1() in Form1
class1Instance.onNnnn += this.HandleClass1Nnn;